# Req.body returns undefined : ExpressJs, NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Please help me I'm having this error for 5 days.

I'm trying to delete data inside of my array on MongoDB
but my `req.body` returns undefined even though I have my body-parser. I'm using `axios.patch` for request.

It works well in my postman but once I sent data that's where the problem occurs.

Here's my axios api call.

```
export const deleteTask = (id,post) => api.patch(`/main/${id}`, post);
```

Here's my schema.

```
 const todoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    task: [String],
    time: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    }
});

const TodoModels = mongoose.model('TodoModels', todoSchema);
```

here's my query.

```
export const deleteTask = async (req,res) => {
   const { id } = req.params;
   console.log(req.body);
   if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))                           
   return res.status(404).json(`Invalid ID`);

await TodoModels.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{$pull:{ task: req.body.task }},{ 
new: true });
}
```

My `req.body` has no task and I don't know why. Once I send data it returns undefined but the ID from req.params is not undefined.

Also once I sent the data from client to backend/server req.body returns this `{ data: '' }` the data I sent became the element. I believe it was supposed to be `{ task: 'data' }`

Comment: can you show us your front-end API call with axios ?

Comment: export const deleteTask = (id,post) => api.patch(`/main/${id}`, post);

Comment: where you define your body arguments like this: `{ task: 'data' }`

Comment: { task: 'data' } is supposed to be result of console.log if I succesfully remove the data inside of array task ...but the result is {  data: ' ' }

Answer (score 0):

If your deleting a record then why are you using `findByIdAndUpdate` ; it should be `findByIdAndDelete`. I have put a sample code you to refer. There are 2ways you can delete a record. You can try them out and see.

Way 1:

```
router.delete('/:id', [auth, admin, validateObjectId], async(req, res) => {
    //check for existing genre
    const movieGenre = await Genre.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    if (!movieGenre) {
        return res.status(404).send('No such movie genre found with given id.');
    }
    res.send(movieGenre);
})
```

---

Way 2:

```
router.delete('/:id', [auth, admin, validateObjectId], async(req, res) => {
    //second way to delete
    let movieGenre = await Genre.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!movieGenre) {
       return res.status(404).send('No such movie genre found with given id.');
     }
    await movieGenre.deleteOne();    
    const index = genres.indexOf(movieGenre);
    genres.splice(index, 1);
    res.send(movieGenre);
})
```

Hope the answer helps you in any way.